# Algorithm for Finding the Extreme Rays of a Polyhedral Cone

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algorithms, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

I would like an algorithm for the following problem:

**Given**: a finite set of vectors $\{\mathbf v_1, ... , \mathbf v_n\} \subset \mathbb R^N$,

**Find**: the extreme rays of the cone 
\begin{equation}
C = \left \{ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \mathbf v_i : x_i \geq 0 \right \}.
\end{equation}

Perhaps another way to say it is that I would like an algorithm for computing the *minimal* generating set of the cone generated by $\{\mathbf v_1, ... , \mathbf v_n\} \subset \mathbb R^N$.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am trying to solve the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  My attention was drawn elsewhere.

Comment: I would a) normalize each vector, b) find the plane perpendicular to the mean vector, c) project each vector onto that plane, and d) use existing algorithms to compute the convex hull.  The points defining the hull define your extremal vectors.  [Something like that...]

Comment: How do you know it forms a cone?  Do you restrict $(v_k)_j > 0$ ?

Comment: Recall the definition of a cone.  Pick an arbitrary $\mathbf v \in C$.  We then ask the question: Is the vector $u \mathbf v \in C$ for any $u \geq 0$?  The answer is "yes".  Therefore, $C$ is a cone.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best I've got so far...

1. Initialize $I := \{1, ... , n \}$.
2. For $j = 1$ to $n$,

   a. Attempt to solve the following LP:
   \begin{equation}
   \begin{aligned}
   \min_{\mathbf x} & \ \ \ 0 \\
   \text{s.t.} &\ \sum_{i \in I\backslash \{j\}} \mathbf v_i x_i=v_j \\
   & \ \ \ \mathbf x \geq \mathbf 0
   \end{aligned}
   \end{equation}
     b. If the the LP is feasible, set $I:= I\backslash \{j\}$.
3. Return $I$

I claim (without proof) that the resulting set $I$ gives the indices of the extreme rays of the cone $C$.